# MySQL replace comma separated values in column with another table find old value to replace with new

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

MySQL table want to replace comma separated values in column with another table value

I have two table

- 1st table  column which has comma separated values(hotkey).
- 2nd Table have oldid & Newid column

I want to search 1st table  column with replace oldid to newid

**action table(1st)**

```
id    hotkey
===   ======
1    2,3,4,5
2    3,2,14,7
3    4,5,6,11
4    9,2,11,5
5    11,5,3,8
```

**tempID table(2nd)**

```
id  oldid   newid 
===  ===    === 
1    5      4  
2    7      6  
3    3      8  
4    9      12  
5    11     14
```

**OUTPUT table (Desired)**

```
id    hotkey
===   ======
1    2,8,4,4
2    8,2,14,6
3    4,4,6,14
4    12,2,14,4
5    14,4,8,8
```

Comment: Fix  your data structure so you have a junction table, rather than storing *numeric ids* inappropriately as a comma delimited string.

Comment: create a new table with each hotkey in separate row, replace the old values and then use group_concat

Answer (score 0):

I Solve by using PHP Script as follows:

```
//db access
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser   = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $database = "dbaname";
    $dbcon = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database,$dbcon) or die ('>>>'.mysql_errno()."Error1 :".mysql_error());

    //find & Replace 
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT oid,nid FROM tempid") or die(mysql_error());
    while($fetch_com=mysql_fetch_array($q))   {  
        $oid=$fetch_com['oid'];
        $nid=$fetch_com['nid'];     
        mysql_query("UPDATE action SET hotkey=REPLACE(hotkey,',$oid,',',$nid,')");  
    }
```